# Meaning of "переделать"

Tags: словоупотребление, глаголы

I know that essentially **переделывать/переделать** means to redo something, or even convert something into something else, yet more and more in conversation I hear it used as if it were an alternate perfective form of simple делать.

For example, a friend on Skype said:

> Дело в том, что я пытаюсь тут кое-какие дела переделать перед тем, как
>   уедем.

I took this to mean that he is trying to **get some things done** before leaving town. Is this accurate? Or is there another meaning I'm not sussing?

Comment: You need to write every definition down—that is, use multiple dictionaries (викисловарь, Lingvo, paper dictionary) to get the best understanding of a verb. Every source has something a bit different, and if you combine them all, and just learn all the variations you won't have such problems :) Th meaning "to do many things" is in there, guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's (almost) right. *Переделать* (or even *Попеределать*) is a colloquial way of saying **to get all (or many) things done**. [Переделать - это...](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/925862).

Note also usage of "*пытаюсь*" and "*кое-какие*". This means "*I'm trying / struggling to*" and "*some / I'm not going to give you any more details*".

That's the whole thing really means "*I've got some problems, but you shouldn't take that into account*".

UPD. Well, that explanation probably gives little compared to just "*I'm trying to*" and "*some business*", but it's a hint of how to crack seemingly awkward construction *some many things* (i.e. some = irrelevant for you; many = worse than I expect).